# Dataframe ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
     Score
0   16-1/4
1        9
2        5
3    3-1/2
4        4
```

I would like to change it to float, such that:

```
     Score
0    16.25
1      9.0
2      5.0
3      3.5
4      4.0
```

To make it, I have developed my code:

```
import pandas as pd

def to_float(value):
    if '-' in value:
        return float(value.split("-")[0].strip('\t')) + (float((value.split("-")[1]).split("/")[0].strip('\t')) / float((value.split("-")[1]).split("/")[1].strip('\t')))
    else:
        return value

df['Score'] = df['Score'].map(to_float)
```

But it turns out an error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Is possible some bad values, it means cannot be processing like this? If yes, how are processing?

Comment: I have removed all those rows with bad values. The remaining should all be the format as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) only if need subtract values:

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].apply(pd.eval)
print (df)
  Score
0  15.75
1   9.00
2   5.00
3   2.50
4   4.00
```

If want `sum` values:

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].replace('-','+', regex=True).apply(pd.eval)
print (df)
   Score
0  16.25
1   9.00
2   5.00
3   3.50
4   4.00
```

Comment: @JAY.Y - what is error? For more 100 rows not working `df['Score'] = pd.eval(df['Score'])`, but `df['Score'].apply(pd.eval)` should working nice

Comment: File "<unknown>", line 1
    ---
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JAY.Y - It seems some data related issue, is possible share this column if not confidental in file?